# How to get the link of "Edit site" button of ecwid

Tags: api, content-management-system

I am using ecwid store. I want to put a button in my portal (my website) to do the same action as the "Edit site" button:

[image: Overview → Manage Instant Site in your Ecwid admin and click the Edit Site button]

My question is, is there any api to get the URL of the action of this button?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Lance, Ecwid Apps&API Support team. Thanks for your question!

Basically, we don't have a direct API for getting the URL of the action of the "Edit Site" button.

This button just redirects you to the editor's page via such a link: `https://my.ecwid.com/edit-starter-site?ownerid={StoreID}&lang={Language}`

Where:

- {StoreID} is replaced with your store ID,
- {Language} is replaced with the two-signs value (for example, `en` for English) of the needed language of the website editor.

Just in case, we also have many opportunities to customize the design and layout. You can find out more about them here: https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/customize-appearance.

Also, feel free to reach out to us via our email ec.apps@lightspeedhq.com if you have any questions, we'll be happy to help!